# Cassandra Hadoop reduce output a map column type java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

I am currently using Hadoop and Cassandra to run Map Reduce tasks.

It works fine, but I am wanting to allow the reduce output to begin inserting data to a Cassandra table with a Map column type.

I have tried just simply changes the value out type to Map in the Reducer but this begins to cause issues internally the cassandra.hadoop implementation as it is always requiring a List.

I have tried to change the OutputValueClass setting, but to no avail.

Has anyone else had luck with outputting something other than List or be able to point me in the direction to understand how it might be achievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what I wanted to do, apologies for answering my own question just thought it may help people in a similar situation. Or will be able to tell me that my new way of thinking is also wrong.

I actually misunderstood what the KeyValueOut for a reducer was actually doing. My assumption was that I could change this value to be anything I wanted to write to Cassandra, and that the underlying Driver would just pick it up. For example Map or Text or Blob. However, I now think that it always has to be a List of ByteBuffers to allow anything to go into Cassandra from Hadoop.

I managed to get it working with the correct type by using the following:

```
     private ByteBuffer ExampleForMapTypes(JSONObject data){
        Map<String, String> mapper = new HashMap<>();            
        String user = data.get("Map_Left").toString();
        String agent = data.get("Map_Right").toString();
        mapper.put(user, agent);

        return MapType
          .getInstance(UTF8Type.instance, UTF8Type.instance)
          .decompose(mapper);
    }
```

The decompose method will return the ByteBuffer and this in turn allows the Cassandra driver to read what the output is going to be and properly handle it in the query. In this example it will output to a Cassandra Column of type Map